# Using sql query on ssis server sql job using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis, sql-job

I want to invoke a sql query/SP on sql job in a ssis server using a powershell script but I don't know how to do that. I've used powershell to run sql queries on sql database but not jobs on ssis. Here is what I have till now-

```
$ssisServer = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server($name_of_server) 
$IntegrationServices = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices" $ssisServer
$catalog = $IntegrationServices.Catalogs[$catalog]
$folder = $catalog.Folders[$folder]    
$project = $folder.Projects[$project]
$sqlJob = $ssisServer.JobServer.Jobs[$existing_job_name]
query= " some sql query "
if ($sqlJob) {
$sqlJob.CurrentRunStatus()
   # here I need to run a query on the job
}
```

The query could be to get details of the job or perform some action on it. Also is this enough as we are just giving the server name here `$sqlJob = $ssisServer.JobServer.Jobs[$existing_job_name]` to get the job which in a particular folder->project->job? I couldn't try this yet and haven't found much resources on it. Please give me some help to work with.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for to me. Does the example in your question work for you already, and you want to add a query on the the job's data? There are a handful of ways to get the job object, but it can depend on what type of authentication you're doing etc. so it's best to start with some working code. Try running the code in your example and adding more info about what data your job returns.

Comment: For your second paragraph, it can be easier to get a specific job by using the sql server provider like `$sqlJob = Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SSIS\localhost\Default\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\MyFolder\Projects\MyProject\Packages\ | Where Name -eq 'MyPackage.dtsx'`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with the SSIS server. But the principle of running SQL queries from SQL is pretty simple.

You should have [proper module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps) or you can use [snapin of SQL](https://amionrails.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/how-to-install-missing-powershell-snap-ins/).

I will continue from the second one.

```
# If you have an SQL server on your server, so this is the possible path where they can be.
$PossiblePaths = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server','C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server'

# Lets check where we have PSProvider.dll and PSSnapins.dll
$PossiblePaths | ForEach-Object {
    Test-Path -Path $_
    {
        $SQLPSProvider = (Get-ChildItem -Filter "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll" -Path $_ -Recurse).FullName
        $SQLPSSnapIn = (Get-ChildItem -Filter "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll" -Path $_ -Recurse).FullName
    }
}

# Lets find Install Utility to add them with it.
$InstallUtil = (Get-ChildItem -Filter "InstallUtil.exe" -Path "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0*" -Recurse).FullName

if (($null -eq $SQLPSProvider) -or ($null -eq $SQLPSSnapIn))
{
    Write-Host "Sorry, SQL PowerShell SnapIn or PowerShell Provider not found." -ForegroundColor Red
}
else
{
    # Adding them to our system.
    Start-Process -FilePath $InstallUtil -ArgumentList "-i $SQLPSProvider"
    Start-Process -FilePath $InstallUtil -ArgumentList "-i $SQLPSSnapIn"
}

# Now they should be in the system and we can add them to our PowerShell session.
Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin -Name SqlServerProviderSnapin100

# Now we should have Invoke-Sqlcmd like if we had SQLServer module.
$SQLServer = "SQL2012"
$SQLInstance = "JustForExample"
$ServerInstance = $SQLServer + '\' + $SQLInstance

# So you typing query for example like attaching DB.
$Query = "CREATE DATABASE ExamleDB ON (FILENAME = `'C:\DBs\ExamleDB.mdf`'), (FILENAME = `'C:\DBs\ExamleDB_log.ldf`') FOR ATTACH"

# And then executing it with Invoke-Sqlcmd like that.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Username 'sa' -Password 'Abcde12345' -Query "Query"
```